# how to pass parameters into an invocable method sf?

Tags: salesforce, apex

```
    Public class AutoConvertLeads
{
    @InvocableMethod
    public static void LeadAssign(List<Id> LeadIds)
    {
            Database.LeadConvert Leadconvert = new Database.LeadConvert();
            Leadconvert.setLeadId(LeadIds[0]);
            lead l= [SELECT Id, email FROM Lead WHERE id=:LeadIds[0]];
            LeadStatus Leads= [SELECT Id, MasterLabel FROM LeadStatus WHERE IsConverted=true LIMIT 1];
        contact[] clist=[select id,name,session__c from contact where email=:l.email limit 1 ];

        if(clist.size()>0){
            contact c=clist[0];
            c.session__c='PUT_THE_VALUE_YOU_WANT_TO_UPDATE_THE_FIELD_WITH'; //Make sure you are inserting value according to field type.
            update c;
        }
        else{    
            Leadconvert.setConvertedStatus(Leads.MasterLabel);
            Leadconvert.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(TRUE); //Remove this line if you want to create an opportunity from Lead Conversion 
            Database.LeadConvertResult Leadconverts = Database.convertLead(Leadconvert);
            System.assert(Leadconverts.isSuccess());
       }
   }
}
```

The session value comes from web to lead form depending on person signing up. It's a picklist. The values are dates as mentioned - May 24; 2 PM - 4 PM, June 28; 9 AM - 12 PM, May 24; 10 AM -12 PM, June 28; 4:30 PM - 7:30 PM, July 26; 9 AM - 12 PM, July 26; 4:30 PM - 7:30 PM.

How can I pass these values into this trigger code for c.session__c ?

Answer (score 0):

In trigger code all the properties from the object are available, so in this case all the properties of led will be available so if you have a trigger like this

```
trigger LeadTrigger on Lead (before insert){
   for(Lead l : Trigger.new){
       System.debug(l.Session__c);
   }
}
```

That would print out the session__ field from the lead.  If you want to pass the value as a function param you could do it like:

```
SomeClass.someStaticMethod(l.Session__c);
//or
new SomeClass().someMethod(l.Session__c);
```

However it might be easier to pass the entire lead record from the trigger or if you pass the ids query the exact fields that you need from the lead in the method.

But from your code it looks like what you want to do is

```
 contact c = clist[0];
 c.session__c = l.MasterLabel;
 update c;
```

Or whatever the field is on lead that you want.  But since you want to map a field on lead to a field on contact why not use lead mapping functionality?

**EDIT**

I Think the title is misleading, I think you meant to ask how to pass params from a trigger into this invocable method.  From the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_InvocableMethod.htm)

> Triggers can’t reference invocable methods

However this can be done via flows and the process builder, so that might be worth looking into.

On a side note you code is not bulkified at all and would lead unexpected results if multiple lead its were passed in with different session codes.  You probably should create a Map> for converted leads where the key is the email (normalized) an the list is a list of converted leads.  Query contacts by the list map keySet() and build a Map where the key is the email (normalized) and do the update value to the lead.whatever__c and up the contact map values

To pass values to the method you listed you would do

```
List<Id> leadIds = new List<Id>();
for(Lead l : [SELECT Id FROM Lead]){ //the query here is an example u can have a list already available
   leadIds.add(l.Id);
}
AutoConvertLeads.LeadAssign(leadIds);
```

But u cant do this from a trigger not directly becuase the doc indicate that it isn't permitted.  You could test to see if you could do it from another class indirectly but I haven't tested that.

Comment: We are using this trigger to auto-convert lead to contacts. Customer can do form as many times as they want. But if they exists in the system which we are checking using email address, then it should update only the session field. There is a session field under Leads that capture the value from website. This field is mapped with c_session in contacts.

Comment: The code you posted is not  trigger, it's an invocable method.  Now that I re-read this I think your question should have been how to pass parameters into an invocable method, not a trigger.